# My Life...Sucks

Tags: riddle, knowledge, video-games

I feel empty inside, but I think writing about it will help me cope.  Here is some prose I wrote:

> Am I dreaming again?
>   This doesn’t look like the dreams that I am used to... Worse.
>   At times I felt I rode on the air, and all was crystal clear.
>   But those dreams shattered, and so often I don’t even recognize myself in the mirror.
>   Time has done that to me.
>   Before, I could eat all I want and not worry about a thing.
>   Now, my skin an unnatural hue, my world overrun by vermin, it’s as if I were under a curse.
>   But we all have a yarn to spin, and I am the star of this one.

Do you know who I am?

**Bonus**

How many references can you find to my games above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> Kirby (clever because "my life *sucks*". heh.)

I only got some of these references. Haven't actually played that many games D:

Am I dreaming again?

> Dream Land sequels (2 and 3?)

This doesn’t look like the dreams that I am used to... Worse. (not sure)

At times I felt I rode on the air, and all was crystal clear.

> Kirby 64: The Crystal Shards

But those dreams shattered, and so often I don’t even recognize myself in the mirror.

> Kirby & the Amazing Mirror

Time has done that to me.
Before, I could eat all I want and not worry about a thing. (not sure if specific reference)

Now, my skin an unnatural hue, my world overrun by vermin, it’s as if I were under a curse.

> Kirby: Canvas Curse

But we all have a yarn to spin, and I am the star of this one.

> Kirby's Epic Yarn

Comment: This seems like a fit :)    Never played a Kirby game before so I guess it was a no-go for me :P

Comment: In retrospect this may have been the reason behind the plurality of "games"  in the Bonus section. Well done.

Comment: @Cat'r'pillar You got it, as well as most of the game references.  That "Time" line was pretty obscure, just commenting on how the older games lacked the capability of creating the color that now defines the series.  Squeak Squad, Super Star, and Air Ride were also intended, if anybody really needs to know.  The Dreamland/Return to/Nightmare in all run together.

Comment: *"I could eat all I want and not worry about a thing"* <- might be a reference to how Kirby sucks enemies in to absorb their powers kinda like how you got the first comment. i'm not sure about the Kirby games but in Super Smash Brothers (at least on the N64) you could suck up your opponents and "eat" them to get their power (ie. Mario you get fireballs) but then you could ditch the power and Kirby is back to normal and repeat the same process

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Nights from Nights into Dreams

This doesn’t look like the dreams that I am used to... Worse.

> The game is about Nightopia, a dream world

At times I felt I rode on the air, and all was crystal clear.

> Nights can fly, Nights has a jewel on him/her

But those dreams shattered, and so often I don’t even recognize myself in the mirror.

> Wizeman the Wicked stole all the dream energy

Time has done that to me.
Before, I could eat all I want and not worry about a thing.

> I'm not sure about this one

Now, my skin an unnatural hue, my world overrun by vermin, it’s as if I were under a curse.

> Nights is purple and pink, and the world is overrun by Nightmaren

But we all have a yarn to spin, and I am the star of this one.

> Nights is the main character

Comment: I see you already saw Cat'r'pillar's answer, which is the intended answer, but I like how much of this lined up with everything I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Kain, from Legacy of Kain? Every line seems to point at a vampire creature.

Some of the items mentioned in the riddle

- > Crystal = games published by Crystal Dynamics
- > Dreams = Was a huge hit on the Dreamcast

Answer (score 0):

> The theme of dreams shattering, the reference to the mirror and the general 'happiness' and 'life' fading away made me thing a LOT of [Lost Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Odyssey). I am unsure if there is more to this puzzle than just a fancy description however...